# Error creating Outlook Rules in Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, powershell-2.0, outlook-2010

I've been messing around with Outlook objects for Powershell. I wanted to create Outlook Rules and I got it to work. Layed the project aside for a while.
When I picked it back up I was unable to create Outlook rules. Note that I did NOT change anything in the code.

### Code generating Outlook Rule

```
 $rules = $ol.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()

 $rule = $rules.Create("spamfilter",[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlRule Type]::olRuleReceive)

    $condition = $rule.Conditions.SenderAddress
    $condition.Enabled = $true
    $condition.Address = @("<sender>")
    $action = $rule.Actions.MoveToFolder
    $action.Enabled = $true

    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MoveOrCopyRuleAction].InvokeMember("Folder",[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::SetProperty,$null,$action,$junk)

    $rules.Save()
```

### The error

> Exception calling "InvokeMember" with "5" argument(s): "Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))"
>   At line:22 char:5
>
> - [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MoveOrCopyRuleAction].InvokeMember("Folde ...
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException

Someone please help me. What seems to be the issue? I'm lost, thanks.

Comment: already defined it earlier in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I defined the `$junk` variable using Redemption outlook library.
This way it's not a legit MAPI object so it doesn't get recognized as a valid parameter.

Instead of defining `$junk = $routlook.GetDefaultFolder(23)`, I had to use `$junk = $ol.Session.DefaultStore.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderJunk)`

But ofcourse I did not provide this information in the question because I didn't think it seemed relevant as nothing else in my script makes a problem of how this folder is defined.