# Powershell to create another folder and move emails in Outlook

Tags: powershell, outlook, rules

I recently found those articles:
[Error creating Outlook Rules in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521975/error-creating-outlook-rules-in-powershell)
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/12/16/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-create-a-new-outlook-inbox-rule/

Unfortunately I'm unable to make one of those to work.
Do you know a similar script (it doesn't matter if it is powershell or not) to create a new folder on inbox and move the emails received from a specific email address?
That would be very useful for a new employee on teams with high amounts of emails per day. It will be nice if we can find something similar to tune it to our needs, the new colleague will have just to run the script on PC and then to have already the folders and rules set for work instead of losing time creating those.

Any response or feedback will be highly appreciated.

PS: I'm new here, looking for some advice/help, any lead will be highly appreciated, I'm not affraid to tune a little script and learn something more about those topics! Is something aside from work, not my day-to-day responsability.

Comment: Why not create a transport rule to do the redirect?

Comment: I'm not sure at what are you refering to...

Comment: Look for Mailflow Transport rules you can set up on the server. That way you can redirect the mail to a shared mailbox or public folder the (new) user has access to. No need for each user to run a script or set up a client rule in Outlook. That way you (the IT guy) keeps control. Docs are easily found, for instance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/exchange/security-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/mail-flow-rules) or [there](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exovoice/2017/07/14/forwarding-rule-from-a-mail-enabled-public-folder/)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a rule. When email received from a specific email address, move it to a specific folder.

[image]

[image]

Selected “From” and “move”.

P.S.  You should checked one of the email which you want move.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, time and effort! But can this be done by a script? Like if you have 30 of those rules and a new employee just to run the script and have all of them done at once.

Comment: No, If you have received a email from a specific folder, this rule will run and move it to the specified folder.